# How to set min-content for a column in tailwind CSS Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

My Layout looks like this [image]

Layout Code:

```
const Layout = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-2">
        <Head>
            <title>Ystream</title>
        </Head>

        <nav className="row-span-2">Sidebar</nav>

        <header>
            <Navbar />
        </header>

        <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
);
};
```

In this grid with 3 blocks, I have 2 columns and I want the width for the first column (Sidebar) to be `min-content` so that I have flexibility to set the width of the side bar the way I want.

To be precise, in CSS you'd do something like `grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr`.

How do replicate this in Tailwind?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

`grid-cols-[min-content_1fr]`

which translates to

```
.grid-cols-\[min-content_1fr\] {
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}
```

[Documentation Reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-columns#arbitrary-values)

Comment: another variation worked for me going off of this example. i needed two columns of text to fit to the content. `grid-cols-[max-content_max-content]`

Comment: this was the perfect solution I was looking for!